# Unity3D C# Random Int Generator

Tags: c#, c++, random, unity-game-engine

I have used C++ for a long time. Now, I just started working with C# in Unity3D. I'm almost complete at finishing an app but I can't seem to find a working int generator in Unity C# (With Min and Max values).
I've tried the following:

```
r = Random.Range(min, max)
```

and

```
Random rand = new Random();
r = rand.next(min, max)
```

Both didn't work. I know in C++ you use:

```
r = rand() % max + min;
```

If you want a random number. But what is the case with Unity C#?
Code:

**EDIT**:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class STarget : MonoBehaviour {
public GameObject inter;
int rand;
public GameObject TS1;
public GameObject TS2;
public GameObject TS3;
public GameObject TS4;
public GameObject TS5;
void Update () {
    rand = Random.Range(1, 6);
}
public void GameRun () {
    switch (rand){
        case 1:
            inter = TS1;
            break;
        case 2:
            inter = TS2;
            break;
        case 3:
            inter = TS3;
            break;
        case 4:
            inter = TS4;
            break;
        case 5:
            inter = TS5;
            break;
    }
    Game.TargetSingle(inter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain "didn't work", you got a exception? you got a result you where not expecting? We can't help you sove a problem if you don't descibe the problem.

Comment: `rand.Next(min,max)` checks out. Make sure you don't fall into [the hole of new-ing identically seeded randoms in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767999/random-number-generator-only-generating-one-random-number)

Comment: `Random.Range(min,max)` should also work. Depending on what you are wanting.

Comment: rand.Next doesn't check out when you are using Unity. Keep in mind, I'm not talking about normal C#.

Comment: Just so you know, rand() % max + min is a really bad way to get a random number in C++. You are skewing the distribution doing this. Furthermore, there are much better methods in C++ to generate random numbers - see [Pseudo-random number generation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Comment: I know about that and I also use C-Time along with Rand() % Min + Max. You are not helping my question by judging my skills with a whole different coding language that I use.

Comment: your script is **TOTALLY BIZARRE**.  it does not  even show where you call GameRun.  your use of Update() is totally bizarre.

Answer (score 3):

Coming from C++, just like `r = rand() % max + min` would give you random numbers between `min` and `max` in C++,it is different in C#. First, you use `Random.Range(min, max)` to get random number in Unity.

Something to really understand is that `Random.Range(min, max)` will **not** really give you random from between `min` and `max` like it does in C++. It will give you a random number between `min` an `(max-1)` if the provided `min` and the `max` are integer.

So when you need random number from `1` to `5`, add `1` to the max(5) or you will get only numbers from `1` to `4`.  `Random.Range(2, 5+1)` or `Random.Range(min, max+1)`. That's probably your problem.

Comment: Remember that it includes the max value if you pass `float` to it though.

Comment: @gjttt1 I think I said that.  "It will give you a random number between min an (max-1) if the provided min and the max are **integer**"

Comment: ah yes, I must've read it too fast! My mistake

Comment: @gjttt1 That's fine. Happens why I read some questions and answers on SO too.

Comment: I knew how it subtracts 1 from the max. My problem is that whenever I run the script, I get the same number repeated.

Comment: I just found out about pseudo-random. Anyone know how to have truly random numbers (With a Min and Max) and not pseudo-random numbers?

Comment: @AustinKugler. Did you try the exact code I posted in my answer? If yes, please put **EDIT** in your question and post your whole C# code so that I will know what exactly you are doing wrong.

Comment: I'll post my code in a minute. Hope you can find the answer!

Comment: @AustinKugler Dude your code is bad. This has nothing to do with your random number function. Where are you calling GameRun () from? you are not calling it from anywhere..... Is this really your whole code?

Comment: @AustinKugler Programmer is right. re-evaluating `Random.Range` in the update function just to use it in the `GameRun()` function like this is strange. Knowing when your call this function will help find the proper solution. The answer you gave is an unnecessarily convoluted way of doing this.

Comment: @AustinKugler as a new user, be sure to TICK any answer.  it's the only way you get points when youa re new, then you avoid moderation. Cheers buddy

Comment: I guess given that the question has been closed it doesn't matter much :O